# How do I get access token from Foursquare?

Tags: java, rest, api, access-token, foursquare

I get code from this direct url with my client id and redirect uri; 
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticateclient_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI

But I can't do it with the rest service. I have to embed this service in my java application and then get access token. I can use that different option,if there is another way you know to get access token.Can you help me?

Comment: You mean you have no substantive server code?

Comment: There should be oauth java libraries out there to help you with this. If you only need this token once, you could use a tool like Postman

Comment: I need java source code to generate access token for social apis -- etc foursquare

Answer (score 2):

The [Foursquare docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#code) walk through the process in great detail. There are 2 options:

- Web Applications Code Flow
- Web Applications Token Flow

Both these options will require you to setup an app through the [Foursquare Developer site](https://foursquare.com/developers/register). You'll need to setup a redirect URL for Foursquare to redirect back to. This is usually a publically accessible URL, but a `locahost` URL also works for testing purposes.

The first, the Code Flow, follows a standard OAuth process:

1. Direct users (generally done through a link or button) to

   ```
   https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI`
   ```
2. If the user accepts, they will be redirected back to

   ```
   https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE
   ```
3. Your server should exchange the code it got in step 2 for an access token. Make a request for

   ```
   https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI&code=CODE
   ```
4. The response will be JSON

   ```
   { access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }
   ```

This access token is what you're looking for.

The second method, the token flow is slightly easier:

1. Redirect users who wish to authenticate to

   ```
   https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
   ```
2. If a user accepts, they will be redirected back to

   ```
   https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
   ```

This `access_token` query param is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your **"App Settings"** page on the developer console of Foursquare.com
2. Set the **"Redirect URL"** under **"Web Addresses"** to [https://www.google.com](https://www.google.com?cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ)
3. Paste and enter the following url in your web browser **(replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your actual client id)**:
   [https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com](https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ)

   This should redirect you to a google page requesting permission to make the connection.
4. Accept and then look at the url of your web browser **(take note at the CODE part of the url to use in step 5)**
   It should look like [https://www.google.com/?code=CODE](https://www.google.com?code=CODE&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ)
5. Copy the code value from the previous step.
   Paste and enter the following into your web browser **(replace placeholders with actual values)**:
   [https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&code=CODE](https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&code=CODE&cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-_-Developer_Ed%2BTech-_-WW_WW-_-SkillsNetwork-Courses-IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DS0701EN-SkillsNetwork-21253531&cm_mmca1=000026UJ&cm_mmca2=10006555&cm_mmca3=M12345678&cvosrc=email.Newsletter.M12345678&cvo_campaign=000026UJ).
6. When you paste the link , This should lead you to a page that gives you your **access token**.

Credit : IBM course intructor.